# Как можно ускорить функцию. Почему то, работает только одно ядро

Tags: c++, многопоточность

```
template<typename FuncVec>
int handle(const vector<int>& v, FuncVec f,  int MAX_THREAD)
{
    vector<future<int>> threads;
    std::vector<int> answers;
    int mid = v.size() / MAX_THREAD; 
    int start = 0, end = start + mid; 
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; ++i)
    {  
        start = mid * i;
        end = start + mid;   
        if (end != (int) v.size() && (int) v.size() - end < mid)
           end = v.size();   
        threads.emplace_back (std::async(std::launch::async, f, v, start, end));     
    }
    for (auto& thread : threads) {
        answers.push_back(thread.get());
    }
    return f(answers, 0, answers.size()); 
}
```

Собственно нужно ускорить данную функцию. Сейчас на 4 потока выдают такие показатели:

> Создаём 10000211 элементов. 
>   (Один поток) Сумма = 45012639 Время = 171.846мс.
>   (Многопоточ) Сумма = 45012639 Время = 193.831мс.

Какие есть идеи?

Выяснили что почему то, работает только одно ядро. Полный код [тут](https://github.com/rvgorlov/Sibsutis-ParComTech/blob/master/Lab3/main1.cpp)

Comment: А вы уверены, что вызывая async таким образом, вы создаете новый поток? Как насчет threads.emplace_back (std::launch::async, async (f, v, start, end));

Comment: Пор большому счету - не мучиться, и запускать однопоточно. Для такой мелкой задачи нет смысла в многопоточности. Накладные расходы на запуск потока оказываются больше, чем выигрыш.

Comment: @Harry - а откуда вы знаете, какую функцию вызывает автор? Это же кусок обобщенного кода.

Comment: @gbg Сужу по приведенным результатам по времени, и по слову "сумма" :)

Comment: Покажите, что у Вас в `f`(FuncVec), что за функция? И чему равно `MAX_THREAD`, и сколько реально ядер доступно?

Comment: По порядку: 
1. Я уверен, что потоки запускаются по тому, что в потоках выполняется операция. 
2. Для мелкой задачи, может быть и не нужно в потоках это делать. А вот для произвольных задач может быть и нужно. Я сделал сумму, только как пример. Можно что угодно запилить. Сумму, умножение, максимум, минимум, итд итп. 
4. Как сказал  @gbg, это обобщенный код, можно запустить любую операцию над векторами. В данном случае делаю вот так [ссылка](https://github.com/rvgorlov/Sibsutis-ParComTech/blob/master/Lab3/main1.cpp). 
5. По поводу MAX_THREAD - доступно 2 ядра, на каждое ядро 2 потока.

Comment: @Nonverbalvk посмотрите на загрузку ядер во время теста.

Comment: @gdb вы правы, действует одно ядро на 100%. Переделал код согласно вашим рекомендация, ситуация не изменилась. Поправил текст вопроса.

Comment: Наверное вопрос надо сформулировать по другому. Как-то в виде: *а когда в вычислительной задаче стоит использовать многопоточность?*  При простом суммировании   элементов вектора (или поиске чего-либо среди них) у Вас ситуация, когда все упирается в производительность памяти (кэша). Что для одного thread, что для нескольких. Функциональные устройства в CPU (а именно их использование и могут реально разделять threads) не обеспечены данными (простаивают). Не знаю, на чем Вы гоняли, у меня Ваша программа показывает для суммы 1.35428мс. (one) / 12.3607мс. (2 threads)

Comment: @avp тогда уж вопрос надо ставить "А в каком случае стоит использовать редукцию?"

Comment: @avp я несколько раз уже менял код в шапке сайта, сейчас время тоже обновлю. Пардоньте.

Comment: Что Вы называете "редукцией"? Пресловутый MapReduce или свертку (различные суммы и т.п.)? А почему Вы решили, что занято только одно ядро?

Comment: @avp 1. Одно ядро занято согласно системному монитору ubuntu, там показано что во время расчётов, только на одном ядре повышается загрузка (притом на 100%). 2. Под редукцией я понимаю как вот [тут на восьмом слайде](http://www.slideshare.net/apaznikov/2015-3-46021179)

Comment: Я понял. Кстати, мой комментарий о том, что все ждет чтения из памяти (по крайней мере по отношению к этой конкретной задаче) неверен. Я попробовал все-таки переписать **на чистом Си  (pthread.h)** в той же Ubuntu 16.04  и та же задача **стала ускоряться**. Максимум получился на 8 потоках (в среднем `(784.636 msec)  (1 threads) (395.663 msec)  (8 threads) (это на 1000 итераций суммирования, на одной итерации разброс очень большой). Получается, все дело в крестовой библиотеке.

Comment: Если интересно, [кинул код в пастебин](http://pastebin.com/VdzQqFk4)